# Discord,js: How to get every user who reacted to an old message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, fetch

I am trying to get the every user, that reacted with a specific emoji to a specific message. So far, I've tried getting the message, then the emoji and then fetiching all the users who reacted with that emoji:

```
    let messages = await client.channels.cache
    .get('920031186871545916')
    .messages.fetch('1074327140138483835');

    const reaction = messages.reactions.cache.get('✅')
    const users = reaction.users.fetch();
```

The result however is a collection with only 100 users, while over 500 users have reacted to the message. I know that the fetch method is limited to only 100 elements, which is why I tried using the "before" property in combination with a loop, as it was suggested on stackoverflow before, when fetching messages.

```
    const users = [];
    const usersToFetch = 520;

    while (users.length < usersToFetch) {
        if (!users.length) {
            const user = await reaction.users.fetch();
            users.push(...user);
            continue;
        }

        const user = await reaction.users.fetch({ limit: 100, before: users[0].id});
        users.push(...user):
    }
```

That however didn't work as I desired. The excact same collection is alwas added to the "users" array in each iteration. I tried a different approach that I've seen on stackoverflow, but the result is excactly the same:

```
    let users = await lots_of_users_getter(reaction, 520);
    async function lots_of_users_getter(reaction, limit) {
        const sum_users = [];
        let last_id;
    
        while (true) {
            const options = { limit: 100 };
            if (last_id) {
                options.before = last_id;
            }
    
            const user = await reaction.users.fetch(options);
            sum_users.push(...user);
            last_id = user.last().id;
    
            if (user.size != 100 || sum_users.length >= limit) {
                break;
            }
        }
    
        return sum_users;
    }
```

I am starting to believe that the "before" property is meant for fetching messages only. Is there any way I can get the ID of each user that reacted to the message?

Answer (score 0):

After doing further research, I learned that the "before" property is in fact only meant for fetching messages, while fetching any other data is strictly limited to the last 100 items.

The only alternative solution to this problem would be to loop through the fetched data, save every user in a different array and then remove their reaction from the message. This however comes at the cost of the reaction being removed permanently.

An alternative would be to set up an event listener that will automatically catch reactions live. Both are not ideal and have noticeable downsides, but so far the limitations of discord's API do not allow any other approach to this specific problem.